# Pass a function reference to a method in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with PHP array_map

I just trying to map a array like:

```
class myClass{ 

    private function mapMyArray(){
        $mapped = array_map(function ($d) { return $this->myFunction($d);}, $raw);
    }

    private function myFunction(){ .... }
}
```

It works as expected mapping a array based on a function.

but when I reffer the function like

```
class myClass{

    private function mapMyArray(){
        $mapped = map($this->myFunction, $raw);
    }

    private function myFunction(){ .... }
}
```

doest not work.

How can I only pass the function reference to the call not a inline function. is that possible?

Why does `$mapped = map($raw, $this->myFunction);` doesn't works?

Comment: I don't know anything about lodash, but if `map` wants a callback like PHP functions then: `$mapped = map($raw, array($this, 'myFunction'));`

Comment: it doesn't works . see the answer below. thanks

Comment: Yes it's the exact same as the answer except using `array()` instead of `[]` which is newer.

Comment: sorry, i didnt see. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to pass the function in as a quoted string, but since you're in a class, you have to pass it in as an array. (See the [documentation for callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), it's mostly found in the comments)

```
 $mapped = map($raw, [$this, 'myFunction']);
```

Comment: Why does $mapped = map($raw, $this->myFunction); doesn't works?

Comment: Because it wasn't designed to work like that, see the linked documentation.

Comment: the documentation shows `$new_numbers = array_map($double, $numbers);` as a possible way to pass callbacks. But it doesn't works with my class.

Comment: That's because `$double` is a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), not a full function, so it doesn't apply to your case.